# Pressured into doing a role I despise

Tags: team-role

I used to be a developer, which I did for 8 years. I started to really resent developing and came to loathe it. Therefore, I gave up that role and decided to retrain and work as DevOps.

My current employer is taking me into meetings almost weekly to pressure (almost harassing) me into working as a developer to help lighten the load of the other developers.

I decline each time stating that I am no longer a developer, and I came here to work as a DevOps. I really do not enjoy development, and developing makes me angry.  The employer preaches that I do not have the company's best interests at heart.

So my real question is: How do I best handle this?  Should I suck it up and just do what they want me to do, and feel like crap every day I am doing it.

Or do I continue to fight my corner, and if so, what would be the most reasonable way to present my thoughts?

Comment: Well, the employer is correct. You put your own interests above the companies. Just like every employee they have ever hired. Do you have a specific question we could answer?

Comment: @nvoigt I have updated the question... to be a question.

Comment: You have missed the third option: you can quit.

Comment: @DaleM Yes I could quit. But I do not think that is a viable option. I enjoy my work, I enjoy the people. This is literally the only gripe I have.

Comment: @jsthornton: you said that you despise your work, then you said that you enjoy it, which is it? If you don't enjoy what you're doing, then it's time to leave and find another job, one where you actually enjoy.

Comment: @LieRyan I outlined that I hate development (the bit they are pressuring me into doing) but love the current role (DevOps).

Comment: If you gave development 8 years you gave it an honest chance.  Do you have DevOps work?   Is this a one time critical project with an end date?

Comment: @Blam I still enjoy developing (independently, and in limited doses). Yes I have a tonne of DevOps work to do, my day is action packed. All of the development work is of course time critical, it always is.

Comment: I am a Devops. You say that you are a Devops. What do you exactly do for them as a Devops? There a few too many employers who advertise for Devops without knowing let alone understanding what Devops do - The term Devops is fashionable and even the most hidebound and ignorant employers want to at least look fashionable.  So again, what are you doing for your company as a Devops?

Comment: How long has it been since you quit development and became a devops person?

Comment: @SigalShaharabani Roughly 3 months.

Comment: DevOps is _both_ development and operations.  If you don't like development, you should have gone for pure operations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See other recent questions about being assigned work outside your original scope. Your job -- meaning what you will be evaluated on -- is whatever management tells you to do. If you have a formal written set of goals for the year that they have said you will be evaluated on,  you can protest that other work interferes with those, but that's likely to just result in your assignment being officially rewritten.

In the end, if the request is *at all* reasonable, you can either pitch in, be evaluated as "not a team player", or *really* be not a team player and threaten to quit. Don't threaten unless you consider that an acceptable outcome.

Your best bet here might have been to have said "it isn't a job I like doing, but if I'm really needed I'll pitch in -- with the understanding that it's only for N weeks, and that this is a sacrifice for me and i'd like the extra effort reflected at year-end review time." You'd be doing development, but your boss would see you as being willing to make an extra effort when needed rather than as a "not my problem" slacker.

Answer (score 4):

In many companies, predominantly small and medium sized, the boundary between development and devops is blurry - particularly if you take "development" to mean "any coding activity at all". An employer who sees someone in a devops role who is capable and not 100% utilised, but refuses to help out to the point where he has to go out and hire more developers instead, is going to see you as a liability. So your current course is going to be career-limiting, if not career-ending.

You could quit and find a large company that maintains strict siloing of work. Alternatively you could - and should anyway - take some time to actually understand yourself better and understand *why* development brings out anger, resentment and "feeling like crap" in you. Especially as you profess to love a closely related field. Is it development itself, or the individuals doing development at your company? You may not like dev work, fine, many don't, but it sounds like an irrationally strong reaction. I would certainly not recommend just "sucking it up" without a decent amount of introspection as it won't solve the underlying problem.

Answer (score 3):

> So my real question is. How do I best handle this. Should I suck it up
>   and just do what they want me to do, and feel like crap every day I am
>   doing it.
>
> Or do I continue to fight my corner, and if so, what would be the most
>   reasonable way to present my thoughts.

I hope when you "decline each time" you have explained to your boss that you really don't want to be a developer.

Your best bet is to sit down with your boss (perhaps during a weekly one-on-one meeting), and explain how you really dislike developing, and that you were specifically hired as DevOps for that reason. Then you could ask "Is there some way we can lighten the load on the developers that doesn't require me to also do  development?"

If your boss still insists that you must develop, then you will need to decide if this is the right company/job for you, or not - then act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The right thing to do would be to say "I will pitch in until required but you will have to hire someone else quickly because such and such job makes the *work I was hired to do* suffer." That way you won't seem like you don't care about the company.

You could always quit if the situation doesn't change or gets worse in 1 year. 
But saying no to work...whatever it may be is not the right way to go. You maybe hired for one reason but it is understood that you will do whatever it takes when your company is in need.

While liking what you do is important, there will always be a few things in your job that you dislike doing but still have to.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a full-time job, and now they want you to do something else, something doesn't add up.

1. Will someone else be doing your devops work?
2. Is there not enough devops work for you to do on a full-time basis?
3. Will you have to do both, i.e. work additional hours?

If you're required to work more hours, you should ask for more money. You may find yourself out of a job if there isn't enough for you to do or they have other people who can.

Can you work something out, so that there is an agreed upon limit to how long you'll need to do this. Sometimes it's easier to fight through something you don't like when you know there is an end in sight.